# Can I provide readonly access to an OpenCV matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv, constants

I have a class which combines a number of OpenCV's `cv::Mat` matrices.

Is there any way I can provide both const accessors allowing clients to read but not write to the underlying data, and non-const accessors allowing clients to read and write the data.

I'm thinking of doing something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    cv::Mat a;

public:
    cv::Mat a() { return a; }
    const cv::Mat& a() const { return a; }
};
```

But will this protect the underlying data from being modified through the const accessor? Or will it just protect cv::Mat's header data?

Comment: Actually, you can check that by yourself by looking up the reference for cv::Mat, and looking which member functions are declared const. These functions can be called on the value returned by `a()`. If some return non-const handles to the underlying data, then no. Otherwise, yes. (Though I'd like that someone confirms this).

Comment: Good point, but the signature for the copy constructor is cv::Mat(const cv::Mat& other), however I know from the standard behaviour that this then allows you to modify the underlying data of the original matrix.

Comment: It depends. If you don't provide a copy constructor, C++ will generate one for you, that initialize each member variable with the corresponding member variable (i.e. `copy.member1` will be initialized with `source.member1` value). From this point, it depends of the member type. If the member variables aren't pointers, there are good chances that it will actually make a copy, and not give away a pointer to the data that you want to protect.

Comment: Yes - it is exactly the pointer case that I am asking about here. OpenCV's matrices allocate all of their data on the heap and share it between copies using reference counting.

Comment: Indeed, looking at the cv::Mat header, they copy pointers to data. Then, it would be very strange that they don't provide any mean of copying without using the same data... Then, I'm not an expert, have you tried your code to see if it actually modifies both Matrices when you create a matrix using the const reference returned by `a()`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are forced to provide access to the `cv::Mat` object itself, you are out of luck. Data access through the `data` pointer is possible even on a `const cv::Mat`. Thus, the code:

```
const cv::Mat test = cv::Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
test.data[3] = 4;
```

Will compile and execute.

However, if you only need to provide access to the data, then you could provide wrapper functions to [`cv::Mat::begin()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-begin) and [`cv::Mat::end()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-end), which do allow read-only access on a `const cv::Mat`:

```
class MyClass
{
    cv::Mat a;

public:
    cv::MatIterator_<uchar> begin() {return a.begin<uchar>();}
    cv::MatConstIterator_<uchar> begin() const {return a.begin<uchar>();}

    cv::MatIterator_<uchar> end() {return a.end<uchar>();}
    cv::MatConstIterator_<uchar> end() const {return a.end<uchar>();}
};

MyClass m;    
const MyClass& mref = m;    
auto it = mref.begin();
*it = 4;                //Compile error here
```

For this example I used `uchar` as the data type, but it's easy enough to make these pass along a template parameter.